# ensureAdmin issue in an Express NodeJS server with passport

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, authentication, server

I know there's the following function:

```
  function ensureAdmin(req, res, next) {
    if (req.user && req.user.username === "admin") {
      return next();
    } else {
      res.send("You do not have access to this web page. Please, contact to the system administrator.");
    }
```

in order to ensure a page is only accessed by the admin. However, I don't find anywhere how to become a user to admin. I don't know if it is worthwhile to know, but I am using MongoDB.

Comment: Your condition is: to ensure a page is only accessed by the "admin" (he's an user named "admin"). Just add role property to your user and use it instead

Comment: but I am logged as "admin" and it do not allow me to access to the page...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your middleware is checking a user's username to see if it is an admin.

If you want to create an admin user, in this case, you'll want to create a user whose username is 'admin' -- that user, and only that user, will be able to access any of the `ensureAdmin` protected routes.